# JavaScript - Uncaught TypeError for all Array methods

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and I'm write a very simple code to practice array. but I got Uncaught TypeError: people.join is not a function as well as for people.reverse and people.sort. Why I got this error message? do I need any external library to use array methods?

```js
var name = ['Jeremy', 'Jeffrey'],
name2 = ["Jennifer", "Jackie"];

var people = name.concat(name2);

var joined = people.join(", ");
var reversed = people.reverse();
var sorted = people.sort();
alert(joined);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue if you are testing it in Chrome is the variable name `name`, in chrome in global scope what ever value you assign to it, that value will be converted to a string so the value of name will be `Jeremy,Jeffrey` not `['Jeremy', 'Jeffrey']`.

This will cause the `concat` to do a string concatenation(value of `people` will be `Jeremy,JeffreyJennifer,Jackie` as a string) and the value of `people` will be of type `String` not array.

Try to just rename the variable to something like `name1` and `name2`

```js
var name1 = ['Jeremy', 'Jeffrey'],
  name2 = ["Jennifer", "Jackie"];

var people = name1.concat(name2);

var joined = people.join(", ");
var reversed = people.reverse();
var sorted = people.sort();
alert(joined);
```

Comment: That's because `name` in global scope refers to [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name), which is a string.